# Excel PowerPivot Relationships

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table, powerpivot

I have an issue when using PowerPivot in Excel 2016.

After creating a relationship between two tables, and afterwards create a pivot table from the data model, the resulting pivot ignores the relationship.

Below you can see my two tables - Table 2 with company code and name, Table 3 with Location, Location name and related company code.

---

As you can see in the resulting pivot it lists *all* locations for *all* companies instead of only the location that actually relates to the company.

[image: 2 tables and a pivot]

---

Here is the link created in the data model, between the Company code in table 1 and company code in table 2.

[image: The two tables are linked]

---

For completeness sake, here is the Pivot Field List used in the first picture.

[image: Pivot Field List]

---

**How do i make the pivot table respect the relation that i have created between the two tables?**

Here is the example file: [example.xmlx](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1UMXN3xNF3BMNyn7nSO_vQBoLpU6lTpgT)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the second table contain **duplicated values**.

Comment: So what you mean is that I basically can't use PowerPivot for this task?

Comment: Incorrect answer.

Answer (score 2):

Put any field from Table3 into the Values area. This will give you a count of the field, but more importantly it will force the relationships into effect.

Here's an example.

[image]

[image]

Comment: He don't display Values filed in Pivot Table. All files in Rows. You can try to create relationship manually in PivotTable with duplicate name.

Comment: Your comment is nonsensical. What does the OP want? He wants the PivotTable to show the relationship. How does he do that? By putting a field in the Values area. Why didn't his image have this? Because he didn't know it would help. What does my answer do? Exactly what he wants.

Comment: Thank you so much for this, Jeffery. I thought I was losing my mind and had almost given it up as a lost cause.